# Passing value from action phase to render phase in portlets

Tags: controller, liferay, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I want to pass string value from action phase to render phase. In these two tutorials [tut1](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363818/JSR-286-Portlets-Action-scoped-Request-Attributes) and [tut2](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/passing-information-from-the-action-phase-to-the-render-phase) its said i can do it by :

*During action(), you can call ActionResponse.setRenderParameter() method to set any String values and retrieve the same using RenderRequest.getParameter() in the following render calls.*

Here is controller of my view mode

**GraphViewController.java**

```
package graphui;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil;
import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;
import javax.portlet.ResourceRequest;
import javax.portlet.ResourceResponse;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.bind.annotation.ActionMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.bind.annotation.RenderMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.bind.annotation.ResourceMapping;

/**
 *
 * Controller for VIEW mode of portlet.
 */
@Controller("graphViewController")
@RequestMapping(value = "VIEW")
public class GraphViewController{

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GraphViewController.class);

    @ActionMapping(GraphUIConstants.SUBMIT_FORM)
    public void handleActionRequest(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)throws Exception {

            logger.info("action phase executed");

            response.setRenderParameter("par1", "par1");

    }

    @RenderMapping
    public ModelAndView handleRenderRequest(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response, ModelMap model) {

      logger.info("render phase executed");  

      logger.info(request.getAttribute("par1"));

    }

}
```

Result of my log:

```
17:43:06,196 INFO  [GraphViewController:56] render phase executed
17:43:06,205 INFO  [GraphViewController:58] null
17:43:09,491 INFO  [GraphViewController:40] action phase executed
17:43:09,498 INFO  [GraphViewController:56] render phase executed
17:43:09,499 INFO  [GraphViewController:58] null
```

**portlet.xml**

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<portlet-app
    xmlns='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd'
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xsi:schemaLocation='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_2_0.xsd'
    version='2.0'>

    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>GraphUI</portlet-name>
        <portlet-class>org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>contextConfigLocation</name>
            <value>/WEB-INF/GraphUI-portlet.xml</value>
        </init-param>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
            <portlet-mode>VIEW</portlet-mode>
            <portlet-mode>EDIT</portlet-mode>
        </supports>
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
        <resource-bundle>content.graph</resource-bundle>
    </portlet>


</portlet-app>
```

Comment: You are setting render-parameter and you are trying to fetch request attribute, that is why it always come as null. Please rectify your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You quote correctly

> *...retrieve the same using RenderRequest*.**getParameter()**

and then you use

```
request.getAttribute("par1")
```

Just follow the tutorial and use `getParameter()` to get your value